# Passing a string value as argument in function

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function that is going to search through data and find experience values where the condition value equals a particular string. This however yields this error:

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
>
> Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions

```
subset = function(data, ttt="string") {
    subset.cond <- subset(data, Condition==ttt) 
    row.cond <- subset.cond[ which(subset.cond$experience != 0),] 
    row.cond$experience <- factor(row.cond$experience) #drop factor levels
    exp.cond <- levels(row.cond$experience) #get experience names
    cond <- data[ which(data$experience==exp.cond ), ] #cleaned data
    return(list(subset.cond=subset.cond,row.cond=row.cond,exp.cond=exp.cond))
}

subset(data=data_1, ttt="drug1")
```

Does anyone have any tips? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: <pre>intensity experience Condition
1.0240835869 n5 drug4
1.6622650638 n5 drug4
0.8888095207 n5 drug4
0.9113421721 n5 drug4
1.2815784814 n11 drug2 
0.5038846664 n11 drug2 
1.5163685324 n11 drug2 
1.315169773 n5 drug1+drug2 
1.2837342548 n5 drug1+drug2 
1.307013202 n5 drug1+drug2 
1.1297371947 n5 drug1+drug2 
0.6114186921 n11 drug1+drug2 
1.0337745362 n11 drug1+drug2 
1.5503374089 n11 drug1+drug2 
1.4897651898 n11 drug1+drug2 
1.4164219704 n9 drug4
0.6683913411 n9 drug4
2.031900503 n9 drug1
3.5488157902 n9 drug1
2.1030339989 n9 drug1
2.1243746251 n9 drug1</pre>

Comment: Is that function going to look at a specific column, or the whole dataset? You can use the `grepl` function that checks if a specific pattern is matched or not. As an example use this `grepl("an", c("use","another","example","man"))`

Answer (score 0):

You have written an infinitely recursive function; did you intend to? The first line of the function `subset` calls `subset` (ie, it calls itself).

You could get this function to work by specifying that you want to use the base function `subset`. ie,

```
subset = function(data, ttt="string") {
    subset.cond <- base::subset(data, Condition==ttt)
    [...]
}
```